# MultipleValidationErrors on dynamodb query

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am trying to query a table and return the results to be used in variables to test data. Below is my code to retrieve the data. The fields in myTables are:

```
AlertType   min    max
----------------------
Velocity     45     100
```

And below errors out

```
    var qparamsV = {
    TableName: "myTable",
    KeyConditions: "AlertType = :v",
    Key: { AlertType: AlertType},
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
        ":v" : "Velocity",
        ":min" : min,
        ":max" : max
    }
};

    dynamo.getItem(qparamsV, function(err, Vdata) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // an error occurred
      } 
    else {
      console.log(Vdata); // successful response
      alert (""+Vdata);
      }
    });
```

But the code throws errors about Key conditions and params

```
MultipleValidationErrors: There were 3 validation errors: * UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params
InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Key['AlertType'] to be a structure
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'ExpressionAttributeValues' found in params at ParamValidator
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `AlertType` is defined as **partition key** and no sort key is defined for the table, the param should look something like below:-

```
var qparamsV = {
    TableName: "myTable",    
    Key: { "AlertType" : {S : "Velocity"}
};
```

Comment: I think we were posting at the same time, yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

hmm, because i failed to notice that

```
getItem doesn't have a KeyConditionExpression
```

just a key

```
Key : { AlertType:"Velocity" }
```